# Can't Understand the outcome

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't understand two different results.
I am trying to get the top 10% of students' GPA, sorted by their grade point average.

[image]

```
select top 10 percent avg (markrate) as GPA
from mark
```

Output:

[image]

Now when I query

```
select top 10 percent avg (markrate) as gpa, studentid
from mark
group by studentid
```

[image]

I am assuming it's because there is the bunch of StudentID 1's and 2's so the average GPA changed

Now

```
  select top 10 percent avg (markrate) as gpa, studentid
  from mark
  group by studentid
  order by gpa
```

How come it ended getting 82 and 2? and Why is this the correct answer?

[image]

Comment: Request you to put sample data and expected output in text format rather than in image.

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
select top 10 percent avg(markrate) as gpa, studentid
from mark
group by studentid
```

Is probably not doing what you expect.  It is aggregating *all* the data by `studentid`.  Then it takes the "top 10 percent" of the result rows.  SQL Server is rounding this to 1 row.

Which row?  An **arbitrary** row.  Using `top` without `order by` is highly discouraged, because you get indeterminate rows.  If you run the query without the `top` (or with `top 100 percent`), you'll see the averages for each student.  One of those rows is arbitrarily chosen.

When you add the `order by gpa`, you get the student with the lowest GPA.  The average is 82 rather than 82.5 because the column is an integer -- so the result is an integer.

I would be more inclined to look at the results using decimal numbers -- and to consider ties:

```
select top 10 percent with ties avg(markrate * 1.0) as gpa, studentid
from mark
group by studentid
order by gpa
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the studentID 2 is the one with lower gpa, as per my calculations it is 82.5 GPA but I guess the datatype for MarkRate is integer, so, it rounds it to 82

Answer (score 0):

**Try out your queries without `top 10 percent`, Hopefully it will clear your doubts.**

**1.** As in your first query without using `top 10 percent`

```
select avg (markrate) as GPA
from mark
```

This will return only one record which will be the `avg` value of `markrate`. If you use `top 10 percent` then it will return 10% rows from the complete result.

**2.** In your second query without using `top 10 percent`

```
select avg (markrate) as gpa, studentid
from mark
group by studentid
```

**3.** This will return four records which will be the `avg` value of `markrate` per `studentid`. If you use `top 10 percent` then it will return 10% rows from these 4 rows result.

In your third query same thing will happen as second but result is sorted by `gpa`, So it shows different result than second one.